# swift firebase storage NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a strange problem, I always used this code to erase images and it always worked, even in this application in other viewControllers it works well.

now I get always:

```
uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'URL scheme must be one of gs://, http://, or https:// '
```

the image to delete is in Markers/gruopId folder

I tried to print url of the image to delete:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/firebase-itsthere.appspot.com/o/Markers%2F-KwKLgt2saNQpZiJuexi%2FC75EE058-61C3-47DB-AFAC-FE18078A0A7F?
```

and imageRef:

```
gs://firebase-*******.appspot.com/Markers/-KwKLgt2saNQpZiJuexi/C75EE058-61C3-47DB-AFAC-FE18078A0A7F
```

Both are ok, so why this??

Please give me a clue, 6 hours wasted!

```js
  let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "MarkersMarkers\(self.groupId!)")

        pictureOfGroup.child(self.groupId!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists(){
                if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                                        
                    for snap in snapshots {
     
                        
                        let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                        
                        let imgToDelete = dict["image"] as! String
                        
                        print(imgToDelete, "imgToDelete")

                        let url = imgToDelete
                        
                        let imageRef = storageRef.storage.reference(forURL: url)
                        
                        print(imageRef)
                        
                          imageRef.delete { (error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                                print("error0: \(String(describing: error))")
                            } else {
                                // File deleted successfully
                                print("deleted")
                            }
                        }
 
                    }
                }
            }
            
        })
        
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem was in this path `Markers\(self.groupId!)` instead your path should be `Markers/\(self.groupId!)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem even if I can't understand it, I was creating the folder of the image manually to save time (yes the name of the folder was right), when I tried to let app create it it could delete with no problem, can someone explain it to me?